# Why am I getting back empty results from Sanity in my Nextjs generateMetadata function?

Tags: next.js, metadata, sanity, app-router

First Next.js project and using app router but for context I already have a Sanity backend in production utilizing a different framework (RIP Gatsby).

Per the Next.js docs on how to dynamically create metadata "[Metadata Object and generateMetadata Options](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/generate-metadata)" I'm to use [`generateMetadata`](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/generate-metadata#generatemetadata-function) and I've been following the docs on Sanity: "[Connect your content to Next.js](https://www.sanity.io/docs/connect-your-content-to-next-js)"

### Code

*app/layout.tsx:*

```
import type { Viewport } from 'next'

import { Providers } from './providers'
import { client } from '@/sanity/lib/client'
import { settingsQuery } from '@/sanity/lib/queries'

type RootLayoutProps = {
  children: React.ReactNode
}

export async function generateMetadata() {
  const settings = await client.fetch(settingsQuery)
  console.log({ settings })
  return {
    title: 'This is a test',
  }
}

export const viewport: Viewport = {
  width: 'device-width',
  initialScale: 1,
  themeColor: '#FFFFFF',
}

const RootLayout = ({ children }: RootLayoutProps) => {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body>
        <Providers>{children}</Providers>
      </body>
    </html>
  )
}

export default RootLayout
```

*sanity/lib/client.tsx:*

```
import { createClient } from 'next-sanity'

import { apiVersion, dataset, projectId } from '@/sanity/lib/api'

export const client = createClient({
  projectId,
  dataset,
  apiVersion,
  useCdn: false,
  perspective: 'published',
})
```

*sanity/lib/api.tsx:*

```
export const dataset = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SANITY_DATASET
export const projectId = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SANITY_PROJECT_ID
export const apiVersion = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SANITY_API_VERSION
```

*sanity/lib/queries:*

```
import { groq } from 'next-sanity'

export const settingsQuery = groq`
  *[_type == "settings"][0] {
    noIndex,
    noFollow
  }
`
```

and to validate my query I used [Vision](https://www.sanity.io/docs/the-vision-plugin) and am getting a return on my groc query.

When I look at the terminal I get back:

```
✓ Compiled in 172ms (1490 modules)
{ settings: null }
```

### Dependencies

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@chakra-ui/next-js": "^2.2.0",
    "@chakra-ui/react": "^2.8.2",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.11.1",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.11.0",
    "@portabletext/react": "^3.0.11",
    "@sanity/image-url": "^1.0.2",
    "framer-motion": "^10.16.5",
    "next": "14.0.3",
    "next-pwa": "^5.6.0",
    "next-sanity": "^6.1.0",
    "react": "^18",
    "react-dom": "^18",
    "react-icons": "^4.12.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^20",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.38",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18",
    "eslint": "^8.54.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "^14.0.3",
    "husky": "^8.0.3",
    "lint-staged": "^15.1.0",
    "prettier": "^3.1.0",
    "prettier-plugin-packagejson": "^2.4.6",
    "typescript": "^5.3.2"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "^20.9.0"
  }
```

### Research

- [NextJs not getting data from sanity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76189132/nextjs-not-getting-data-from-sanity?rq=2)
- [Next.js - How to Get Data From Sanity Using SWR](https://www.sanity.io/answers/next-js-how-to-get-data-from-sanity-using-swr)
- [Cant fetch data from sanity using next.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77065471/cant-fetch-data-from-sanity-using-next-js)
- [Check data exists in sanity with next.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69326631/check-data-exists-in-sanity-with-next-js)
- [fecthing sanity data with next js and reach them , coming empty array,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73926870/fecthing-sanity-data-with-next-js-and-reach-them-coming-empty-array)

Why am I not able to get back the backend Sanity data for `generateMetadata` in my Next.js app?